# Android Wear Watchface Background will not center

Tags: android, android-canvas, wear-os

I am making an android watchface and I noticed that no matter what I do, my background image will not center completly.This was tested on both an emulator and LG G Watch with the same effects.

```
 @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
        int width = bounds.width();
        int height = bounds.height();
        float mCenterX = width / 2f;
        float mCenterY = height / 2f;
        if (isInAmbientMode()) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundBitmap, mCenterX, mCenterY, null);
        }

 @Override
    public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
        super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);

        // Load resources that have alternate values for round watches.
        Resources resources = FaceJake.this.getResources();
        boolean isRound = insets.isRound();
        mXOffset = resources.getDimension(isRound
                ? R.dimen.digital_x_offset_round : R.dimen.digital_x_offset);
        float textSize = resources.getDimension(isRound
                ? R.dimen.digital_text_size_round : R.dimen.digital_text_size);


 public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onCreate(holder);

        setWatchFaceStyle(new WatchFaceStyle.Builder(FaceJake.this)
                .setCardPeekMode(WatchFaceStyle.PEEK_MODE_VARIABLE)
                .setBackgroundVisibility(WatchFaceStyle.BACKGROUND_VISIBILITY_INTERRUPTIVE)
                .setShowSystemUiTime(false)
                .setAcceptsTapEvents(true)
                .build());
        Resources resources = FaceJake.this.getResources();

        mYOffset = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.digital_y_offset);
        Drawable backgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.jakehappy);
        mBackgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) backgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint = createTextPaint(resources.getColor(R.color.digital_text));
        mTime = new Time();
```

The background image is 320x320 and without this code, it was also not centered. I even tried changing the value by the Center X and Y floats to many different values, even 100f, yet this did not help all the way. 
 (Left image: screenshot. Right: image for background)

[image][image]

Comment: The screenshot  on the left is 280x280 (as is the G Watch R, not sure about your emulator). I don't see anything in your code to account for the difference in size between the screen and your 320px image?

Comment: So should I resize the image to 280? I also have a Moto 360 Gen 1 if that helps.

Comment: There are several ways to handle a size differential, but all I'm saying is that if you don't do *something*, there's no reason to expect your background to be centered.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I thought that 320 was the standard size, and that by doing that, I did not need to account for screen size. I will try resizing it to 280 px or I will try this resize bitmap code I found. I'll make an answer for whichever works.

Comment: Apperently, background images for wear need to be 320x320. But putting it inside of the HDPI folder helped a little bit. But I will work more on this

Comment: Have you looked at the standard WatchFace example, that should scale the image appropriately for any display size: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace particularly look here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/watchface/AnalogWatchFaceService.java#L315

Comment: @WaynePiekarski I have but it seems that I had a problem with the image itself, as well as some code that I somehow left out. Your comment works. Thanks.